# Which version of Ubuntu to download to use in Parallels on Mac OS X

Tags: 12.04

Which version of Ubuntu do I need to download to create a VM in Parallels on my Mac?

32 bit  vs  64 bit  ?
i386  vs  AMD version ?

Comment: We need hardware information to determine this.  What Mac do you have?

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, amd64 refers to x86_64. If you have Parallels you have Intel hardware. Grab the amd64 version and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hello! And welcome to AskUbuntu! If this is not fully answering the question, without more of a detailed response, a comment would probably be better. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. I did not have that privilege when I posted.